# Keep Dropdown open in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I want to keep the combobox open when the user click on it to make multiple selection and to close only when the user clicks outside the combobox. It closes when the user click on one of the selected items. How to keep it open?

```
const ComboBox: (props: ComboBoxProps) => JSX.Element = ({
  ...
}) => {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [connect, setConnect] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [dropDownString, setDropDownString] = useState<string>('Select...');

  const toggle = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement>): void => {
    const target = e.target as HTMLDivElement;
    if (
      (isOpen && (!keepOpen || target.id === getFieldId('dropdown_field'))) ||
      target.id === getFieldId('expand')
    ) {
      setIsOpen(!isOpen);
      const dropdownY = e.clientY;
      if (dropdownY > innerHeight - 220) {
        setConnect(true);
      }
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className={`dropdown${isOpen ? ' open' : ''}`}>
      <label><span>{label}</span></label>
      <div>
        <div
          ...
          onClick={toggle}
        >
          <input
            ...
            type="text"
            value={dropDownString}
          />
          <div>
            <Elements
              items={items}
              selected={selected}
              onChange={(selected): void => {
                onChange(selected);
              }}
              multiple={multiple}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
export default ComboBox;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a custom hook you can use to accomplish this.

Basically, you want to get rid of that toggle function. Instead you want `onClick={open}`. Then you want to do something like this.

```
const ComboBox: (props: ComboBoxProps) => JSX.Element = ({
  ...
}) => {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [dropDownString, setDropDownString] = useState<string>('Select...');

  const ref = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

  function open() {
    // your logic here.
  }

  function close() {
    // your logic here.
  }

  useOnClickOutside(ref, close)

  return (
    <div className={`dropdown${isOpen ? ' open' : ''}`}>
      <label><span>{label}</span></label>
      <div>
        <div
          ...
          onClick={open}
          ref={ref}
        >
          <input
            ...
            type="text"
            value={dropDownString}
          />
          <div>
            <Elements
              items={items}
              selected={selected}
              onChange={(selected): void => {
                onChange(selected);
              }}
              multiple={multiple}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
export default ComboBox;
```

You're creating a reference to a DOM node with `useRef`, assigning it to that JSX element. Then the `useOnClickOutside` function will use that reference to detect when clicks are done outside of your div, and fire the close function when that happens.